# How can I return value from this child function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, for-loop, return

cannot return the dat[0] value from the inner function

```
let ite = fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
  }
  dat = files.filter(item => item[1] == files.length);
  return dat[0];
});
```

Comment: what is the value of ```dat``` if you do a ```console.log(JSON.stringify(dat))``` inside the function before the final return? That will be a good place to start your debugging.

Comment: Can you elaborate more the function what it should be doing? also this nodejs not normal javascript, add should nodejs tag to your question.

Comment: Why you need return `dat[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from the function which will called when the operation will be finished. So returning from that function doesn't change the value of your variable.

You can use `readdirSync`

```
const res = fs.readdirSync(directoryPath);
```

If you don't want it to be sync you can use `fs.promises` with async await

```
let res;
(async function() {
   res = await fs.promises.readdir("");
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to read `sync` reading because it can block the main `thread`. You could use a `callback` function by passing it as *parameter* to another function.

```
 function getData(onSuccess, onError) {
     fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
             onError('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
        }
        dat = files.filter(item => item[1] == files.length);
        onSuccess(dat[0]);
     });
 }

 getData(function(data){
     console.log(data);
 }, function(error){
     //error here
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make it as a promise method to run the code async. Here we don't block any thread. It will be running asynchronously.

```
function getData(directoryPath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
            if (err) {
                reject('Unable to scan directory: ' + err.message);
            }
            dat = files.filter(item => item[1] == files.length);
            resolve(dat[0]);
         });
    });
 }

 getData(directoryPath).then((data) => {
     console.log(data);
 }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
 });

 // or

 try {
     let data = await getData(directoryPath);
 } catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
 }
```